# Architecture; coupling search system with nosql database

Tags: elasticsearch, database-design, architecture, search-engine, nosql

Choosing a nosql DB like Cassandra, Couchbase, Mango etc is endless debate. All of their nice perks, and we could debate about which one is better, but at the end their main use case stay to set and get data. 
Even if they all have indexing, views, or search features, the requests are not made to be intensively made on one cluster. 
Their is ways to bypass some of these problems, more or less cleanly, but fundamentally this not for what this database have been made.

In other hand, we have system like Elastic Search, which are really bad at doing get/set, but great at indexing your data.

So a naive solution would be, I am going to save my data into a NoSql db, and indexing it into ES (or similar system).

Now, supporting several system at the same time definitely has its issues, maintenance problem, increase of point of failurs, complexity of the code ...

So my question is, people who tried such a solution in production, would you advise to go that way or it is mistake in your opinion?